# Permission problems using cordova media-capture and file-transfer

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm trying to capture a video using cordova-plugin-media-capture and upload it with cordova-plugin-file-transfer.

Heres the media-capture call:

```
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(
    app.view.controller.success,
    app.view.controller.error,
    {limit: 1}
);
```

And the success callback:

```
app.view.controller.success = function(event)
{
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey = 'data[Request][video]';
        options.fileName = event[0].name;
        options.mimeType = event[0].type;
        options.chunkedMode = false;

    var transfer = new FileTransfer();

    transfer.upload(
        event[0].localURL,
        app.view.uploadurl,
        app.view.controller.uploaded,
        app.view.controller.error,
        options,
        true
    );
};
```

For now, the uploaded and error callbacks only do a console.log() of the arguments.

The problem is that it runs fine on android 5.1 but gives me a EACESS error (transfer.upload call) on android 6.0. Error code 1, can't read file).

I can confirm that the video has been recorded, it shows in the gallery app. But the file-transfer plugin can't read it.

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have encoded your uri : `app.view.uploadurl`

like this : `encodeURI("http://some.server.com/upload.php")`

Answer (score 0):

As per these two github issues there is no way to use capture video to get a video file without also using MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and running the risk of
getting excluded from the play store

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/issues/426

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture/issues/125